# How to make dropdown based one JSON, and selected parameter taken from another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I got this JS code, which suppose to make list of statuses in dropdown:

```
$.getJSON('/statuses', {
        ajax: 'true'
    }, function (data) {
        var html;
        var len = data.length;
        html += '<select id="status" class="form-control selectpicker" width="150" style="width: 150px">';
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                + data[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        html += '</select>';
        $('#status').html(html);
    });
```

This part is working, but now I have to make sure that selected option is equals to other JSON. I tried something like this in other getJSON:

```
    status += '<select id="status" class="form-control selectpicker" width="150" style="width: 150px">';
    status += '<option value="' + data.status + '" selected="selected">' + data.status + '</option>';
    status += '</select>'
```

...it selects it, but also duplicates the status. How can I make it proper way?

Comment: what do you mean with duplicates the status? You already made the option in the first getJSON?

Comment: Yeah. For example, there is three options created first and than I add another, one of those three. It adds up to list as selected, and if I click on dropdown, it contains three option plus one more, depending on JSON data. like: 1, 2, 3, 1<selected>.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to, as you're iterating over your 2nd set of JSON data, check & compare it to the values of all the existing <option> elements, then only add a new one if it's distinct? Is that correct?

Comment: I basically just add "status" as selected option, from second JSON to those three

Comment: I want to know how to make one of options 'selected', depending on what status I get from 2nd JSON. I kinda did it, but it is messy, not appropriate way.

Comment: why don't you use '$('#status').val(data.status);' ?

Answer (score 0):

On the second bit of code you are parsing new HTML, that is why you get duplicate. To just select an option try this:

```
$('#status option[value="'+ data.status +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```